# Create a background pattern in CSS

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have the following image

[image]

which has this angled stripe pattern in it, I was wondering how I could create this pattern with CSS as a background pattern.

cheers,
es

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(edit: I added a second example in the codepen)

Similar to an already given answer, but with an addition to avoid gradients:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EyNwOq

Give it a repating linear gradient background, but to avoid the gradients and to only get two separate colors, do it as follows (play around with the settings to get the stripe width and colors you like):

```
background: repeating-linear-gradient( -45deg, #000 0px, #000 5px, #333 6px, #333 11px, #000 12px);
```

Answer (score 2):

it can be done with background:repeating-linear-gradient

```css
div { 
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background:
  repeating-linear-gradient( -45deg,#000, #333 1px,#000 1px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `linear-gradient` in the background and make small boxes which makes it easy to alter the width of the stripes (10px times 10px in my example) which then form the background like this:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

h4 {
  padding-top: 150px;
}

.gradient-box {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  border: none;
  font: normal 100%/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(84,84,84,0) 0, rgba(84,84,84,0) 40%, rgba(29,29,29,1) 40%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 59%, rgba(58,58,58,0) 59%, rgba(63,63,63,0) 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0, rgba(0,0,0,1) 7%, rgba(79,79,79,0) 7%, rgba(63,63,63,0) 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(-225deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0, rgba(0,0,0,1) 7%, rgba(79,79,79,0) 7%, rgba(63,63,63,0) 100%), rgba(33,29,29,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(84,84,84,0) 0, rgba(84,84,84,0) 40%, rgba(29,29,29,1) 40%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 59%, rgba(58,58,58,0) 59%, rgba(63,63,63,0) 100%), -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0, rgba(0,0,0,1) 7%, rgba(79,79,79,0) 7%, rgba(63,63,63,0) 100%), -moz-linear-gradient(315deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0, rgba(0,0,0,1) 7%, rgba(79,79,79,0) 7%, rgba(63,63,63,0) 100%), rgba(33,29,29,1);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(84,84,84,0) 0, rgba(84,84,84,0) 40%, rgba(29,29,29,1) 40%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 59%, rgba(58,58,58,0) 59%, rgba(63,63,63,0) 100%), linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0, rgba(0,0,0,1) 7%, rgba(79,79,79,0) 7%, rgba(63,63,63,0) 100%), linear-gradient(315deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0, rgba(0,0,0,1) 7%, rgba(79,79,79,0) 7%, rgba(63,63,63,0) 100%), rgba(33,29,29,1);
  -webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
  background-origin: padding-box;
  -webkit-background-clip: border-box;
  background-clip: border-box;
  -webkit-background-size: 10px 10px;
  background-size: 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient-box">
  <h4>Awesome striped background</h4>
</div>
```

You should be able to change the `background-size` and the `linear-gradient` colours very easily to fit what you want to achieve.