# CSS Background Stripes on div

Tags: html, css

So I have a square div and i'm trying to get the background to basically look like this :

[image]

I've had a look around, and since this question has been asked a lot i've seen CSS gradients used.

I've been playing about and ended up with:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(
  180deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 29%,
  transparent 20%,
  transparent 51%,
  rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%,
  rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%,
  transparent 75%,
  transparent);
```

However, gradients seem to blend the colours from one to another instead of having a sharp difference like below.

What should  I be doing to achieve the picture?

Comment: That picture is hypnotising. :( But the gradients are supposed to be blending in. They are not going to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a background pattern in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37965625/create-a-background-pattern-in-css)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

try this :

```css
div#stripes {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #000 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, #000 50%, #000 75%, transparent 75%, #fff);
  background-size: 50px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="stripes">

</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/t2e2zrn2/)

Answer (score 16):

You can do like this:

```
background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, #de9dd4, #de9dd4 5px, white 5px, white 10px);
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9y34mfmr/)

Answer (score 11):

A more flexible and elegant solution found here : https://css-tricks.com/stripes-css/

```css
#stripes {
  height: 200px;
  width: 2000px;
  background-color:yellow;
}

.stripes {
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(
      45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 10px,
      #000 10px,
      #000 20px
  );
}
```

```html
<div id="stripes" class="stripes"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ns8rn7r3/4/

Answer (score 2):

Please use this CSS:

```
body{
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, white 25%, #000 25%, #000 50%, white 50%, white 75%, #000 75%);
  background-size:98px 98.9px;
}
```

See in [action here](https://jsfiddle.net/a527g0x4/)